# Check if the file lies in the specified interval in unix

Tags: shell-script

I have a csv file place at a location say /NAS/Target with the below format:

```
Scorecard_Name,Path,FileName,Time_Interval_HRS
Scorecard_LDO_cust_BTS,"/NAS/data/Bank_SEN",Cust.EXT,12
Scorecard_LDO_Bank_BTS,"/NAS/data/Bank_SEN",Bank.EXT,6
```

This csv files has the details of all the scorecard jobs and the file details which triggers this job. The file extension can be .EXT or .txt

I want to check the timestamp of the files cust.ext, Bank.ext and any other file in the csv and identify if the file is old or new based on the defined interval (Interval_HRS) field.

Also, I want to redirect the output to another file with the scorecard name and the flag (old or new).

I am new to unix and currently exploring ways to do it.
I will post my effrots if I find anything useful.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Amit. What is the "timestamp" of the files? Maybe the last modification time? Also I see the "Time_Interval" is an integer, what does this number mean? 6 days? 6 years? something else? And what is the test for a file and this number to decide if file is "new" or "old"? Please clarify these things by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/618288/edit) your question.

Comment: There are many questions discussing how to extract a comma separated field (`awk` or `cut`). You need to define your time interval - what time unit is it using? What type of UNIX/Linux system will this be running on? (That helps determine the set of available tools.) Will the files always be in `/NAS/Target` or will they be found in the location defined by the `Path` field in the datafile? Showing us what you've tried already will be useful - it's usually better to help someone fix their own code than write new code from scratch

Comment: Yes, the last modification time. Also the interval is in hours. If the modification time lies in between the current time + the interval then it's new file.

Comment: Will the files always be in /NAS/Target or will they be found in the location defined by the Path field in the datafile?-- the file be in the path specified in the data file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include extra information. Don't write it here in the comments. When you [edit] your question don't just add extras with "edit" or "update" but take the time to include the new information as if you'd had it originally. Make the question as easy to read and understand as possible

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -MText::CSV -le '
  $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1});
  $csv->getline(STDIN); # skip input header
  $csv->print(*STDOUT, ["Scorecard_Name", "Status"]);

  while($row = $csv->getline(STDIN)) {
    $file = "$row->[1]/$row->[2]";
    $age = -M $file; # in days
    if (defined($age)) {
      $status = $age * 24 < $row->[3] ? "new" : "old";
    } else {
      $status = "unknown"; # file not there or not accessible
    }
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, [$row->[0], $status])
  }' < /NAS/Target/file.csv > result.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I have not used Perl much and was ideally looking for a unix shell script for this.

Comment: @Amit, that's a Unix shell script that calls `perl`. Shells are tools to run other commands. `perl` is one of those commands that can parse csv files properly (provided a CSV handling module like `Text::CSV` is installed).

Comment: Hi @Stephane-- I am getting syntax error : syntax error at Files.pl line 1, near "-le"

Comment: Hi @stephane Can you please let me know the error which we are getting here?

Comment: @Amit, again, that's *shell* code that runs the `perl` command to interpret an inline script with its stdin and stdout redirected. You just need to copy-paste that at the prompt of your shell. Or if you want to make it a script, put that in a file but with no shebang or a `#! /bin/sh -` shebang, not a `perl` one. The error you get suggests you're trying to have `perl` interpret that code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I ran that as a shell script but it seems perl libraries are missing. Below error: 
Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Yes, you'd need the corresponding module. On a Debian-based system, that would be with `apt install libtext-csv-perl` for instance.